# How to get RSSI values in wireshark captures

Tags: mac, osx-mountain-lion, wireshark

I'm running Mountain Lion and have Wireshark 1.8.3.  I want to display the RSSI of each packet but I seem unable to do so.  I went to Edit->Preferences->User Interface->Columns and select RSSI to be shown by adding a column showing 'IEEE 802.11 RSSI', yet I do not get any RSSI values for any packet.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

On OS X (and on Linux, with most if not all adapters, and perhaps even on some *BSDs), you can only get radio information such as signal strength if you capture in monitor mode.  If you don't capture in monitor mode, you'll get fake-Ethernet headers, not 802.11 headers, you'll only see data frames, and you won't get any radio information.